# Heroku nodejs- redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: node.js, progressive-web-apps

I am working on `Progressive Web App` and when testing it with Lighthouse I get:

Does not redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS

My server is in nodejs and it is on Heroku. I was trying to add this code:

```
app.get('*',function(req,res,next){
  if(req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']!='https'){
    res.redirect(`https://${req.header('host')}${req.url}`)
  }else{
    next()
  }
})
```

But it didn't help. Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: Have you seen the [Heroku documentation on the subject?](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls)

Comment: Yes. However it didn't help. I needed to change that on frontend.

Comment: Not a great idea, see my comment to your answer as well as my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You want to enforce this on the server, and the easiest way to do that is to use the [express-sslify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sslify) module.  From the documents:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var enforce = require('express-sslify');

var app = express();

// Use enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true }) since you're behind Heroku's reverse proxy
app.use(enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true }));

// The rest of your express config.
```

Note also that  you want to employ `app.use()` as I did, rather than `app.get()` as you did in order to make sure you're covering *all* requests to your app, not just GETs.

Answer (score 1):

listen on port 80 and redirect to https

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(301,{Location: `https://${req.headers.host}${req.url}`});
  res.end();
});

server.listen(80);
```

Comment: I am using express and I don't know how to connect your code with my current one which is: var server = require('http').Server(app);

Comment: This code listening on port 80 for http requests.
And after that you have to listen on port 443 (https) with express where you can serve your webapp.
`var https = require('https');`
# you have to read to privateKey and certificate from where you store them
`var options = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};`
`var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app);`

Answer (score 1):

Why not check [req.protocol](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.protocol)?

```
app.get('*',function(req,res,next){
  if(req.protocol !== 'https'){
    res.redirect(`https://${req.header('host')}${req.url}`)
  }else{
    next()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I have been using with no apparent drawbacks is to use the node package `ssl-express-www`, and that is assuming you are using Express which it looks like you are.

The code is extremely simple:

First install the package `npm i ssl-express-www`

Then in your server file:

```
const secure = require("ssl-express-www")

const app = express();

app.use(secure)
```

That's literally it! Put that code at the top before your route handlers and it will do all the 'heavy-lifting' for you.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. As I was using React, I just created file, on client side, called `static.json` in the main folder, and added that:

```
{
 "root": "build/",
  "https_only": true,
  "headers": {
    "/**": {
      "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=7776000"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a great idea.  This will allow a malicious man-in-the-middle to simply serve a slightly modified version of your client.  You really want to enforce this on the server.

Comment: I have contacted Heroku Dev Team and that was a solution they suggested.

Comment: That doesn't make me feel better.